# Whether a structure pointer needs to be declared in Gorm Mode() function

Tags: go-gorm

When I use Gorm Update function to Update a row in the database, do I need to declare struct pointer in the Model? When I write code, sometimes I declare pointer and sometimes I declare struct directly, no error will be reported. But when I am in UT, I'd like to Omit fields in a database that have foreign keys, but with the Omit function I have to declare struct Pointers in the Model otherwise GORM will report an error, which is weird. Update function RETURNING (tX.statement. aneurysm ["RETURNING"];) Different situations are different processing results, I want to know what is its mechanism? Can someone answer it for me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIHGJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJVUX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf5Dd.png)

Comment: Don't put screenshots of the code, share the code in the question, and write sentences with paragraphs please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.